# Access violation Exception when calling Com object method in inno setup

Tags: object, com, automation, inno-setup

I am using IUnknown based COM technique in inno setup to access the methods of DLL. i can register and can get the object correctly but when i call the method inno showed me an exception:access voilation at address 0xxxxx in module mydll.dll write of address 0xabcd. my inno code is as follows. please help me in this regard.

```
hWnd :=  FindWindowByWindowName(VideoForm.Caption);
Obj := CreateComObject(StringToGuid('{CC6C749C-FADD-4ee5-80CF-11536CCF2206}'));
Obj2:=IShellLinkW(Obj);

 Obj2.pluginStart(hWnd,'appVideo',VideoForm.Caption,'',0)
```

end;

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't get that casting to `IShellLinkW` and calling `pluginStart` method on it. So what is that COM object ?

Comment: Given that `IShellLinkW` is a shell interface relating to shortcut files, it's incredibly unlikely that it has a `pluginStart` method.  (More likely, the object you're trying to create either doesn't exist or doesn't implement `IShellLinkW`.)  To fix this you need to use the correct interfaces, and you should check if the variant is null before trying to call it.

Comment: I've noticed that you probably tried to reach me by reporting [`an issue`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-media-player/issues/detail?id=2), but that's been a wrong place. You can always [`edit your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23338941/edit) and include at least how your interface is defined and why did you try to cast to `IShellLinkW` and call `pluginStart` method on it. My best guess is that you're missing your interface declaration in the Inno Setup script and since it inherits from `IShellLinkW`, you've tried to call a method of it...

Comment: ...we can try to translate your interface to Inno Setup Pascal Script but we don't know it, so it's impossible to help. The `pluginStart` method is surely unknown to the `IShellLinkW` interface, so that attempt is wrong.